# How do I read a config value in JavaScript where the config value is dynamic?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, config

[Reading web.config from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910095/reading-web-config-from-javascript) shows how to read a web.config from JavaScript. I have a config file with [Region]Helpline

```
<appSettings>
<add key="CVAHelpline" value="(555) 555-2341"/>
<add key="DSAHelpline" value="(555) 555-3421"/>
<add key="EBHelpline" value="(555) 555-4321"/>
</appSettings>
```

As in the earlier post, this works:

```
<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CVAHelpline"] %>
```

I want

```
var region = = $("#ddlGeoArea").val();
var helpConfig = region + "helpLine";
```

and then

```
var helpConfigTxt = "<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[" + helpConfig;  + "] %>";
```

If this is possible, I need the proper syntax so I can write the text and that text changes when the person changes the region.

Comment: If it were not 'dynamic' then you would simply hard code it, no?

Comment: At the moment you are trying to use `helpConfig`, the `<%= ... %>` part was already evaluated. `<%= ... %>` is executed on the **server** *before* the output is sent to the client. The variable `helpConfig` only exists on the client. However, you can read *all* the configuration settings and add them to JS and then read them in JS.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're implying is impossible.
I can think of two ways for you to achieve this:

1. Preload all the codes:

   ```
   var preloadedCodeArray = ["<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[line1] %>", 
                             "<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[line2] %>", 
                             "<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[line3] %>"];
   ```

   Or via a method that returns the wanted string:

   ```
   var preloadedCodeArray = ["<%= GetAllConfigurationLines() %>"];
   ```
2. Use AJAX calls to retrieve the wanted line (this would require of you to build a specific http-handler for handling the calls and returning the wanted code line). something in the form of:

   ```
   function getConfigLine(lineNum) {
       var config;
       $.ajax("../WebConfigLineHandle.ashx?line=" + lineNum, {
           complete: function(data) {
               config = data;
           },
           async: false
       });

       return config;
   }
   ```