# error when reading webconfig app settings in javascript

Tags: javascript, master-pages, appsettings

i have researched the internet and could not find a solution to my problem.
 i am trying to read my appsettings key in my master page using javascript.

i have tried the following :

```
<add key="var1" value="SomeValue"/>
<script>
function appsettings(){

var value=<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["var1"].ToString() %>';

</script>
```

when i run this it gives an error "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)."

also tried

```
var value='ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["var1"].ToString()'
```

the above just assigns the entire string 'ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["var1"].ToString()' into value variable.

i have looked at the following links

```
 [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091539/how-can-i-read-key-value-from-web-config-in-javascript-file/31092791
  [2]: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/77917/Read-Configuration-Settings-of-Web-config-using-Ja
```