# how to read the web.config file values in office addins office.js

Tags: office365-apps, office-js

i am developing an excel add-ins using office.js, i want to keep the different configuration settings in the web.config files, and read those settings in the java-script file. how to do that.

is office add-in sample project is MVC asp.net project, should i be returning the view from there and my source location in manifest point to that view.

please guide me to correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is not something that is Office Add-in specific. You would you would use the same approach as with a regular website.  For example, see [Reading web.config from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910095/reading-web-config-from-javascript).

In terms of the manifest start URL, you can point it at any web-browsable page, it doesn't have to end with .html. So you can use an aspx or MVC view page. Alternatively, you can have an html/js/css page that makes an AJAX web service call to your own web API that returns you the settings. If I may recommend, see my blog post for how to [create a web service for an Office Add-in using the ASP.NET Web API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/06/10/create-a-web-service-for-an-app-for-office-using-the-asp-net-web-api/).

Hope this helps!

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: my question was because we need to give location of page to load in the manifest file. should i be giving controller path which would return view, to be able to read the value in config file. if i have separate html file to show in task pane and if the aspnet project is differnt i wont able to read and use that webconfig value in the html page.

Comment: You can use any web-browsable page, it doesn't have to end with .html.  So you can use an aspx or MVP view page.  Or you can have an html page that makes an Ajax web service call to your own web API that returns you the settings.

Comment: thank you so much. actually i do not wanted to use view, i feel i should go with webapi, as i have already developed my page in html and i am not that good with view thing..can you please update your answer so that it should look generic, i will mark as answered. thanks

Comment: Updated answer to reflect information in the comments