# What is the use of web.config file in Office Web Addin project?

Tags: office-js

When I create a new office web addin project in Visual Studio 2019, I see web.config file in the solution. What are the different things I can do using web.config file in office web addin project?

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard file for configuring a web application (which is what an add-in is) that is hosted on the IIS/Asp.net stack. See [web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-5.0). "What are the different things I can do using a web.config..." would require an article-length answer.

Comment: I want to have environment variables in web.config and transform the it on publish to set the environment variables. I am thinking to have one value in environment variables for dev/testing and another value for production. The web addin should read the environment variable and use it in the app. The answer in this [post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849274/how-to-read-the-web-config-file-values-in-office-addins-office-js) suggests to make a web service request to get the required value instead of from the web.config. This is confusing. Can office addin read value from web.config?

Comment: Server side code can read values from the web.config.