# How to run the same angularjs apps (.NET MVC 5) for a different SQL Server folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am very new to AngularJS and SQL Server configuration issues.

I have developed AngularJS apps using ASP.NET MVC 5. Basically, the front-end is based on AngularJS and the back-end is in C#.

Once we put the apps in SQL Server, the application is working as expected. To run the application, I get the SurveyID = 1 (say) from the Web.Config file.

Right now, I want to run the same apps using a different SurveyID for multiple surveys.

```
a. The server folder is \\Survey with SurveyID = 1
b. The server folder is \\Survey2 with SurveyID = 2
c. The server folder is \\Survey3 with SurveyID = 3
d. The server folder is \\Survey4 with SurveyID = 4
```

Even though the apps put into a different folder structure, the apps always reads the root folder which happens to be \Survey with SurveyID = 1

But in the MVC Layout_Page, I am using the HTML tag 
I wonder if this is the cause of the root problem.

Right now, How Can I tell the angularJS apps which one is the root directory based on the Web.Config SurveyID

How can I resolve this issue?
Inside MVC HOME Controller

```
            DataAccessSurvey data;
            int surveyID;
            public HomeController()
            {
                data = new DataAccessSurvey();
                surveyID =   Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SurveyId"]);

            }

    [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetSurveyInfoData()
        {
            var surveyData = data.GetSurveyById(surveyID);
            var Survey = new Survey();
            //the rest of the code to populate the Survey related data
        }
```

In Angular Controller.jS I call the following way

```
    SurveyServices.getSurveyData()
                    .then(function (result) {
                        //alert("Success getSurveyData GetSurveyInfoData");
                        vm.SurveyInfo = result.data;
                   }
```

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1910140/5015356) about embedding Web.Config values in your JavaScript code. Specifically, you can register them with your AngularJS application using `.constant()` ([docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant)) and import them into your component or controller.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .constant('SurveyID', <%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SurveyID"] %>)
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['SurveyID', function(SurveyID) { ... }]);
```

Comment: I do get the SurveyID value from the Web.Config to populate the Survey Questions. But it does not resolve my issue. I think how can I tell the apps to read the Survey ID from a different Server Folder? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you unless I know the folder structure and where you communicate with the API. Probably you're using `$http` or `$resource`, right?

Comment: you  are correct I am using $http to get the SurveyID.

Comment: And do you mean with "different folders" that the surveyID is part of the URL? Because in that case, you can just do something like `path/to/Survey${surveyID}` and insert the variable like that

Comment: it is a Survey Apps. I want to run this apps for a different survey at the same time. So, IIS server has a separate folder for each survey. For each Survey, id is stored in the Web.Config. ID is not part of the URL. The root is Survey and the structure are like Survey/Survey1, Survey/Survey2, Survey/Survey3 like that.

Comment: If the surveyID is not part of the URL, is it part of the request body in any way? Otherwise, I don't think this has anything to do with AngularJS

Comment: I get the SurveyID during the controller init() method. In this method, I called the MVC Action Method using $http to get the SurveyID from the web.config file.

Comment: It is difficult to understand without code. Can you add some to your question? If the MVC Action Method is in the backend, why not just use the SurveyID over there?

Comment: I have added MVC Controller Action Method and Angular Controller how I call the Survey-related action method to populate the Survey questions for each Survey ID. Thanks

Comment: I don't really get why AngularJS needs to know the server folder if that is not reflected in the URL or in the body. It doesn't seem like AngularJS needs to know the SurveyID, because it's all handled very well in the MVC HomeController. Please explain what you want to do and why you choose to do it like this, because apparently you're having multiple servers with only one database/file storage?

Comment: my manager wants to run the Survey apps for multiple surveys at the same time (kind of monkeysurvey types). He tells me that the apps always reads the root folder structure. My assumption is that once he creates multiple folders for the same application, the relative path gets messed up and the Angular JS does not know how to get the data for the other folders. I could be wrong because I am not very familiar with the IIS server setup.

Comment: If the surveys are stored as files on different servers, and each survey has only one SurveyID set, it shouldn't matter. In any case, it's not an angularJS issue, but an issue about reading files from a relative path using ASP.NET

Comment: if it is an relative path issue, how can I resolve? Please let me know. In the internet,the articles say that it is easy to set up different relative path with ng-build command, but I am not using new Angular.