# how to read web config values through Home.js in office Add-in?

Tags: javascript, web-config, office-js, office-addins

When I create a new office web addin project in Visual Studio 2019, I see web.config file in the solution. Now I am trying to access the web.config value using home.js.

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910095/reading-web-config-from-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading web.config from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910095/reading-web-config-from-javascript)

Comment: No, I want these changes in simple HTML and javascript. I created an Add-in project so need web.config value access in javascript I used mentioned solution but it does not work for me.